# make strings out of chars from argv[1] at runtime

Tags: c, string, pointers

Learning some C syntax here, and I've run into something that I find a bit confusing.
I am trying to make two functions:

1)    `char* extractCharacters(char** input)`
Take argv[1] from main and extract the first two characters (they can be any readable ascii characters)make a string out of them. Return that string.

2)    `char* concatenate(char* string1, char* string2)`
Take the string returned from function 1 above, and concatenate it with a second input string supplied by main.

For this one, I have:

```
char* concatenate(char* string1, char* string2)
{
char* concatenated = malloc(strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+1);
strcpy(concatenated, string1);
strcat(concatenated, string2}
return concatenated
}
```

When it comes to function 1, I understand `argv` is a the pointer of a pointer, I just dont really get how to go from that to a string at runtime. Sorry if the question is a bit noobish.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example? I must've read your question 10 times and I'm still having problems understanding what you're asking.

Comment: your question is not clear, please post more code and explain better your problem.

Comment: Say you launch the program with ./program just. I would like to be able to take the "ju" from "just", and concatenate it to another string, say "stice". The output of function 2 should be "justice"

Comment: @home_wrecker, please, I posted a solution for you. Could you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this solution:

```
char* concatenate(char* string1, char* string2)
{
    char* concatenated = (char*)malloc(strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+1);
    sprintf(concatenated, "%s%s", string1, string2);
    return concatenated;
}

int main(char* argv[], int argc )
{
   char string1[100];
   char* string2 = "stice";
   strncpy(string1, argv[1], 2);
   char* string3 = concatenate( string1, string2);

}
```

Comment: That was great. The only bit I dont understand is the (char*) in front of the malloc. Could you explain please?

Comment: Yes, malloc returns a void* pointer while you need a char* pointer, so you have to make a cast. Please, vote for solution is ok :)

Comment: @home_wrecker You don't need a cast, it is completely optional.

Comment: My C++ compiler (c11) wants the cast, otherwise shows me following error: [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(19): E2034 Cannot convert 'void *' to 'char *'

Comment: C++ requires the cast. C does not.

Comment: @AngeloDM Note the tag, it is `c`.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` points to an array of character pointers. Each character pointer points to a c string.

```
char* third_string = argv[2] ;

char second_char_of_third_string = argv[2][1] ;
```

`extractCharacters()` should be take a character pointer instead, just like `concatenate()`.